# What does 'load_utility' do in COSMOS?

Tags: ruby, cosmos

Ruby has 'require' and 'load' so 'load_utility' probably does something similar to 'load'? When should it be used over 'require' and 'load'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [COSMOS](https://cosmosrb.com), 'load_utility' instruments your ruby script for use in scripting. Instrumenting means that it displays the line that is executing when it runs. This is different from simply doing a Ruby 'load' because that code is not instrumented and will execute directly in the Ruby interpreter without showing the line by line execution.

For more information, please read this [Require vs Load](https://cosmosrb.com/news/2017/11/13/require_vs_load/) blog post.